# Unit Tests with read-only custom Datasource in Cakephp

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am currently in the process of writing some Unit Tests for my CakePHP application. I have a custom `datasource` for a few of my models. This is a *read only* datasource. I want to run some unit tests using this datasource but can't seem to get it working.

I have created a fixture with the following at the top:

```
public $useDbConfig = 'test_datafeeds';
```

But I get a load of errors thrown back at me. If I delete all my fixtures from the DataTest it works, however it uses all the actual data in the actual database too - for my tests I would prefer to use the dummy data I have sent up for the data in my database.

I have managed to create static fixtures using dummy data to mock the datasource, but i'd also prefer the option to use the actual datasource in tests.

Some of the errors I am getting:

```
Notice: Undefined index: prefix in lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeFixtureManager.php on line 169

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeFixtureManager.php on line 171

Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in lib/Cake/TestSuite/Fixture/CakeFixtureManager.php on line 174

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DataFeedSource::execute() in lib/Cake/Test/Suite/Fixture/CakeTestFixture.php on line 194
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it, but it works for me. I have removed
    public $useDbConfig = 'test_datafeeds';
from the fixture and it works. It seems that just by having the test_datafeed configuration in my config file it works.

Quite handy as I can keep my static fixture as its and then toggle the test_datafeed on and off by commenting it out.

Comment: not going to accept this as the answer right away in case someone else comes along.